# Adding font color in CkEditor5 react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CKeditor5 with Classic Editor and upload plugin in reactJs. I want to add font color functionality in text editor. As per documentation I've tried to install and use @ckeditor/ckeditor5-font, but it is giving me error of "ckeditor-duplicated-modules". How to add font color in the text editor?

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
```

```
<CKEditor
                    config={{
                      extraPlugins: [uploadPlugin],
                    }}
                    editor={ClassicEditor}
                    data={value}
                    // onInit={(editor) => {}}
                    onReady={(editor) => {}}
                    onChange={this.handleCk5change}
                    className="ckeditor-custom"
                  />
```